# Adding a hex value to a string of bits

Tags: decimal, tcl, addition, hex

I have an issue with increasing a string of bits which represents an IPv4 address.
The string looks like this `"E8 00 00 64"`
What I'm trying to do is this: when adding a value `aSourceAddress` to this string, the last bit should be increased, i.e. when adding 5, the string should look like this `"E8 00 00 69"`. However, when I add 6, I get `"E8 00 00 70"` and what I am hoping to get is `"E8 00 00 6A"`.
Logically it's simple, I need to convert the `aSourceAddress` variable to hex and add it to 64, but my output is, again, 70.
So I guess what I'm asking is, how can I get a result in hex.

This is kinda what I have so far.

```
proc dec2hex {dec_num} {return [format %04X $dec_num]}
set lEndOfAddress {format 0x%x[expr { 0x64 + 0x[dec2hex $aSourceAddress] }]}
set lCompareIpAddr "E8 00 00"
append lCompareIpAddr " $lEndOfAddress"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should take advantage of the `#` flag, which appends the `0x` as necessary, instead of adding it on your own. Also, I'm not sure I understand the padding (the `4`), but I'll leave that be:

```
proc dec2hex {dec_num} {return [format %0#4X $dec_num]}
```

I think your brackets and/or spacing was botched in your editing, but here's the next line, fixed:

```
set lEndOfAddress [format %02X [expr { 0x64 + [dec2hex $aSourceAddress] }]]
```

And simplifying your last line,

```
set lCompareIpAddr "E8 00 00 $lEndOfAddress"
```

I get the results,

```
% set aSourceAddress 6
5
% proc dec2hex {dec_num} {return [format %0#4X $dec_num]}
% set lEndOfAddress [format %02X [expr { 0x64 + [dec2hex $aSourceAddress] }]]
6A
% set lCompareIpAddr "E8 00 00 $lEndOfAddress"
E8 00 00 6A
```

Comment: +1 Though I would have expected an example with `$aSourceAddress = 6` instead. And on a last note, might as well make use of `string toupper` to change `6a` to `6A`.

Comment: @Jerry - Great points. Edited and reran code just to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: Using `%02X` (with a capital letter) makes the `format` produce the right output without an extra `string toupper`.

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for the quick response. I do have a problem still..
When I use the # flag, it doesn't work. Without it, everything goes well until 6C, then I get an 

ABORT: can't use invalid octal number as operand of "+"
    while executing
"expr { 0x64 + [dec2hex $aSourceAddress] }"

Comment: Edited answer to use `X` as opposed to `string upper`. @user2576486 - What do you mean by the `#` flag "not working"? What is your input and what is your output? Without the `#` flag, the reason you get that error might be that you're still prepending zeroes, and numbers that start with a 0 (and not `0x`) are considered octal numbers, but of course octal numbers cannot contain digits greater than 7. Also, make sure you've copied the above code exactly, and not mistakenly prepending a 0 manually, still, or something like that.